# Check if a class contains a tensorflow object

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, serialization, pickle

I have a class from which different child classes are inherited. I use `pickle` to save/load class instances, but some child classes use `tensorflow`, for which a different method should be implemented.
How should I check to see if an object has a `tensorflow` attribute and how should I efficiently save/load objects to be able to construct the object?

Answer (score 0):

> How should I check to see if an object has a tensorflow attribute?

You can use:

```
hasattr(obj, 'tensorflow')
```

See the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr).

See the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model) to see how you can save and load models.